# What type of function is this (derivative of a hyperbola)?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

The derivative of the hyperbola $$f(x)=\frac{b}{a}\sqrt {a^2+x^2}$$

is

$$f'(x)=\frac{bx}{a\sqrt {a^2+x^2}}$$

[The graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRatX.png) (for $a=b=1$) looks somewhat like a Sigmoid function, but I honestly cannot see the connection.

Can anybody help me out by telling me what type of function this is? Since I am not that good at maths, can you please thorougly explain exactly why it is that type of function?

Futhermore, the double-derivative is

$$f''(x)=\frac{ab}{(x^2+a^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$$

What type of function is this? [The graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/280Bp.png) (for $a=b=1$) looks somewhat like a Bell curve.

I am looking forwards to your answers. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is just what it is. Functions don't have types.

Comment: @Mikael: Could you please explain what you mean by "type"? (The derivative is an algebraic function, but not a rational function, if that's the type of thing you have in mind.)

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang: By "type" I mean linear functions, exponential functions, polynomials, logistic growth etc. Perhaps the functions above fit into a certain category of functions, with which they could be compared?

Answer (score 0):

Your function $f'$ is a bounded, [odd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Odd_functions), strictly increasing [algebraic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function): The graph
$$
y = f'(x) = \frac{bx}{a\sqrt{a^{2} + x^{2}}}
\tag{1}
$$
is part of the algebraic plane curve
$$
b^{2}x^{2} - a^{2}y^{2}(a^{2} + x^{2}) = 0.
\tag{2}
$$
(The locus (2) consists of the graph (1) and the graph $y = -f'(x)$ obtained by reflection across the $x$-axis. Because $f'$ is odd, reflecting its graph across the $y$-axis gives the same graph as reflecting across the $x$-axis.)

If $b \neq 0$, the function $f'$ is not [rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function): There are distinct horizontal asymptotes at $\infty$ and $-\infty$, while a rational function with a horizontal asymptote has the same limit at $\pm\infty$.

The function $f''$ is, similarly, an [even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Even_functions), irrational algebraic function. The graph
$$
y = f''(x) = \frac{ab}{(a^{2} + x^{2})^{3/2}}
$$
is defined by the two-variable polynomial
$$
y^{2}(a^{2} + x^{2})^{3} - a^{2} b^{2} = 0.
$$

Though the functions $f'$ and $f''$ bear qualitative resemblance to a [logistic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function), or to a [Gaussian bell curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and its cumulative distribution, they are substantially different, approaching their respective asymptotes [polynomially fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) rather than exponentially fast.